# How can I write a PHP function that takes an arbitrary number of parameters?

Tags: php, function

I am trying to find a way to create a function in PHP that will wrap a SQL query given in the parameter so that I can prevent SQL Injection in the function that can then be called many times throughout my application. Rather than repeating the same statements for each and every query.

For example say I have the following PHP code that prepares and executes a query to prevent SQL injection:

```
$name = "$_POST['name']";
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE test_name = ?');
$stmt->execute(array($name));
```

For each query my application will need to make these statements will need to be repeated. I want a way to prevent having to do this each time, rather I would simply want to call a function each time and pass in the query.

How would I wrap this in a function that can then be called whenever I need to make a query in my application, **given that I do not know in advance the amount of parameters that would need to be parameterized.** The above query has one parameterized query, but each query may have a different amount.

Note:

I am using [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) statements

Something like this:

```
public function query($query)
    {
    // statements here
    }
```

Where the query is passed in as a parameter.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: You're looking for `func_num_args` and `func_get_args` to get arbitrary number of parameters from a function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php

Comment: Or `...$params` [if you are using PHP 5.6+](http://php.net/manual/functions.arguments.php)

Comment: or `function query($query, array $params)`

Comment: @kingkero I am using 5.4.12 on WAMP server

Comment: To be frank: *really?!* That's exactly *two lines* of code. How much shorter does it need to be? Also, these two lines abstract a hugely complicated process the result of which can potentially take minutes to compute. I think there's something to be said for abstracting operations to an *appropriate* number of lines depending on the complexity of the task; two lines for querying an SQL server seems very appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I am using something like this that might work for you.

**Example:**

```
function superQuery($query, $params, $type = null) {
    $pdo = new pdo(...);
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($params);
    if ($type === "select") {
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        return $result;
    } else {
        return $stmt;
}

$query = "SELECT row FROM column WHERE row1 = ? AND row2 = ?";
$params = [$row1, $row2];
$type = "select";
$row = selectQuery($query, $params, $type);

// returns multidimensional array or true/false depending if argument is used //
```

There's lots of ways you can do it. You could also pass a count argument if you wanted to return a count instead of a result set. But hopefully this points you in the right direction and gives you some ideas.